# Font Trebuchet MS won't work

Tags: html, css

So I got this the body css as followed:

```
body { 
     font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

There is no other css rule that overwrites this rule (checked with Firebug). For some reason my Trebuchet MS font doesn't work. In Firebug it just shows

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

The font is active on my computer so that shouldn't be the problem. If I write Trebuchet MS infront of Arial in Firebug it does work.

**Solution:** Always make sure to clear your cache/turn cache off when developing websites..

Comment: Do you have a live example of this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't..

Comment: Hi Nijn! I think the last sentence of your sentence is a bit unclear? Do you mean "instead of Arial"?

Comment: No, I meant that when I change the css in the firebug css inspector to 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; it does load the font.

Comment: You're editing the wrong CSS rule/file or overriding it later. There's just no other explanation.

Comment: The issue occurs in all elements or in some? With the `body {...}` rule some elements such as `input`, `select` won't listen this rule

Comment: Does it work if you delete all other css and leave this as the only rule?

Comment: I'm going to burn my computer down... It was yet again a cache related. Clearing my cache resolved the issue, DOH...

Comment: Do you know the `Web developer` plugin? It is available in Firefox and Chrome and among its many features it can disable cache. It will save you from such situations like this

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will surely try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Always make sure to clear your cache/turn cache off when developing websites..